# php newbie looking for advice on improving code in Magento

Tags: php, magento, refactoring, helper

I am coding to add dynamic [hreflang elements](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/189077?hl=en) to the `<head>` section of each of our web pages on our Magento store.

I've coded some helper functions in Magento which I call from our html/head.phtml template file.  I use them to get the corresponding url for each Magento store view. They are working fine but I feel the code could be better.

For instance:

1. I have a some variables which I reuse in each function can I define them as class global vars and call them within each function as required.  I thought the global key word would achieve this but it doesn't seem to work in Magento. e.g. the `$englishItalian` variable.
2. Is there any other way I can refactor the code in my helper class / data.php?
3. Should I move the code from the helper class to a Magento block?  How would I call this from the template?
4. Also is there anyway to check if a URL exists before returning it?

All advice welcome

**html/head.phtml Template**

```
<link rel="alternate" href="<?php echo Mage::helper('utility')->getEnglishDefaultUrl(); ?>" hreflang="en" />
<link rel="alternate" href="<?php echo Mage::helper('utility')->getEnglishUsUrl(); ?>" hreflang="en-us" />
<link rel="alternate" href="<?php echo Mage::helper('utility')->getItalianItalyUrl() ?>" hreflang="it-it" />
<link rel="alternate" href="<?php echo Mage::helper('utility')->getEnglishCanadaUrl(); ?>" hreflang="en-ca" />
<link rel="alternate" href="<?php echo Mage::helper('utility')->getFrenchCanadaUrl(); ?>" hreflang="fr-ca" />
```

**Namespace/Utility/Helper/Data.php Helper Class**

```
<?php

class Namespace_Utility_Helper_Data extends Mage_Core_Helper_Abstract
{
    public function getEnglishDefaultUrl()
    {
        $curStoreId = Mage::app()->getStore()->getStoreId(); // get current store view ID
        $href = Mage::getUrl('', array('_current' => true,'_use_rewrite' => true,'_store' => 1,));  // get url for particular tore view
        $href = $this->cleanUrl($href); // remove query strings from url
        if ($curStoreId == 4) {  // translate href depending on current store view ID
            $href = $this->transItalianToEnglish($href);
            return $href;
        } elseif($curStoreId == 6){
            $href = $this->transFrenchToEnglish($href);
            return $href;
        } else {
            return $href;
        }
    }

    public function getEnglishUsUrl()
    {
        $curStoreId = Mage::app()->getStore()->getStoreId();
        $href = Mage::getUrl('', array('_current' => true,'_use_rewrite' => true,'_store' => 2,));
        $href = $this->cleanUrl($href);
        if ($curStoreId == 4) {
            $href = $this->transItalianToEnglish($href);
            return $href;
        } elseif($curStoreId == 6){
            $href = $this->transFrenchToEnglish($href);
            return $href;
        } else {
            return $href;
        }
    }

    public function getItalianItalyUrl()
    {
        $curStoreId = Mage::app()->getStore()->getStoreId();
        $href = Mage::getUrl('', array('_current' => true,'_use_rewrite' => true,'_store' => 4,));
        $href = $this->cleanUrl($href);
        if ($curStoreId == 1  || $curStoreId == 2 || $curStoreId == 5 ) {
            $href = $this->transEnglishToItalian($href);
            return $href;
        }elseif ($curStoreId == 6){
            $href = $this->transFrenchToItalian($href);
            return $href;
        }else {
            return $href;
        }
    }

    public function getEnglishCanadaUrl()
    {
        $curStoreId = Mage::app()->getStore()->getStoreId();
        $href = Mage::getUrl('', array('_current' => true,'_use_rewrite' => true,'_store' => 5,));
        $href = $this->cleanUrl($href);
        if ($curStoreId == 4) {
            $href = $this->transItalianToEnglish($href);
            return $href;
        } elseif($curStoreId == 6){
            $href = $this->transFrenchToEnglish($href);
            return $href;
        } else {
            return $href;
        }
    }

    public function getFrenchCanadaUrl()
    {
        $curStoreId = Mage::app()->getStore()->getStoreId();
        $href = Mage::getUrl('', array('_current' => true,'_use_rewrite' => true,'_store' => 6,));
        $href = $this->cleanUrl($href);
        if ($curStoreId == 1  || $curStoreId == 2 || $curStoreId == 5 ) {
            $href = $this->transEnglishToFrench($href);
            return $href;
        }elseif ($curStoreId == 4){
            $href = $this->transItalianToFrench($href);
            return $href;
        }else {
            return $href;
        }
    }

    public function cleanUrl($url)  // remove query string from href
    {
        $url = preg_replace('/\?.*/', '', $url);
        return $url;
    }

    public function transEnglishToItalian($url)
    {
        $englishItalian = array(  // use an associative array to store translations for urls
            "products"=>"prodotti",
            "science"=>"scienza",
            "terms-and-conditions"=>"termini-e-condizioni",
            "shipping"=>"spedizione",
        );
        foreach ($englishItalian as $key => $value) {  // iterate over the array
            if (strpos($url,$key) !== false) {  // check if url has english translation word
                $url = str_replace($key, $value, $url);  // replace the english work with the Italian word
            }
        }
        return $url;
    }

    public function transItalianToEnglish($url)
    {
        $englishItalian = array(
            "products"=>"prodotti",
            "science"=>"scienza",
            "terms-and-conditions"=>"termini-e-condizioni",
            "shipping"=>"spedizione",
        );
        foreach ($englishItalian as $key => $value) {
            if (strpos($url,$value) !== false) {
                $url = str_replace($value, $key, $url);
            }
        }
        return $url;
    }

    public function transEnglishToFrench($url)
    {
        $englishFrench = array(
            "products"=>"produits",
            "shipping"=>"livraison",
        );
        foreach ($englishFrench as $key => $value) {
            if (strpos($url,$key) !== false) {
                $url = str_replace($key, $value, $url);
            }
        }
        return $url;
    }
    public function transFrenchToEnglish($url)
    {
        $englishFrench = array(
            "products"=>"produits",
            "shipping"=>"livraison",
        );
        foreach ($englishFrench as $key => $value) {
            if (strpos($url,$value) !== false) {
                $url = str_replace($value, $key, $url);
            }
        }
        return $url;
    }

    public function transItalianToFrench($url)
    {
        $italianFrench = array(
            "prodotti"=>"produits",
            "scienza"=>"science",
            "termini-e-condizioni"=>"terms-and-conditions",
            "spedizione"=>"livraison",
        );
        foreach ($italianFrench as $key => $value) {
            if (strpos($url,$key) !== false) {
                $url = str_replace($key, $value, $url);
            }
        }
        return $url;
    }

    public function transFrenchToItalian($url)
    {
        $italianFrench = array(
            "prodotti"=>"produits",
            "scienza"=>"science",
            "termini-e-condizioni"=>"terms-and-conditions",
            "spedizione"=>"livraison",
        );
        foreach ($italianFrench as $key => $value) {
            if (strpos($url,$value) !== false) {
                $url = str_replace($value, $key, $url);
            }
        }
        return $url;
    }
}
```

Comment: You can pull `$englishItalian`, `$englishFrench`, and `$italianFrench` out of the functions. Declare them once up top `protected $englishItalian = ...`. Then inside the functions when you reference it, you will use `$this->englishItalian`.

Comment: @slapyo that gave a `Fatal error: Cannot access empty property in .../Utility/Helper/Data.php on line 128`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Move the arrays that you repeat up to the top.

**Namespace/Utility/Helper/Data.php Helper Class**

```
<?php

class Namespace_Utility_Helper_Data extends Mage_Core_Helper_Abstract
{
    protected $englishItalian = array(
        "products"=>"prodotti",
        "science"=>"scienza",
        "terms-and-conditions"=>"termini-e-condizioni",
        "shipping"=>"spedizione",
    );

    protected $englishFrench = array(
        "products"=>"produits",
        "shipping"=>"livraison",
    );

    protected $italianFrench = array(
        "prodotti"=>"produits",
        "scienza"=>"science",
        "termini-e-condizioni"=>"terms-and-conditions",
        "spedizione"=>"livraison",
    );

    public function getEnglishDefaultUrl()
    {
        $curStoreId = Mage::app()->getStore()->getStoreId(); // get current store view ID
        $href = Mage::getUrl('', array('_current' => true,'_use_rewrite' => true,'_store' => 1,));  // get url for particular tore view
        $href = $this->cleanUrl($href); // remove query strings from url
        if ($curStoreId == 4) {  // translate href depending on current store view ID
            $href = $this->transItalianToEnglish($href);
            return $href;
        } elseif($curStoreId == 6){
            $href = $this->transFrenchToEnglish($href);
            return $href;
        } else {
            return $href;
        }
    }

    public function getEnglishUsUrl()
    {
        $curStoreId = Mage::app()->getStore()->getStoreId();
        $href = Mage::getUrl('', array('_current' => true,'_use_rewrite' => true,'_store' => 2,));
        $href = $this->cleanUrl($href);
        if ($curStoreId == 4) {
            $href = $this->transItalianToEnglish($href);
            return $href;
        } elseif($curStoreId == 6){
            $href = $this->transFrenchToEnglish($href);
            return $href;
        } else {
            return $href;
        }
    }

    public function getItalianItalyUrl()
    {
        $curStoreId = Mage::app()->getStore()->getStoreId();
        $href = Mage::getUrl('', array('_current' => true,'_use_rewrite' => true,'_store' => 4,));
        $href = $this->cleanUrl($href);
        if ($curStoreId == 1  || $curStoreId == 2 || $curStoreId == 5 ) {
            $href = $this->transEnglishToItalian($href);
            return $href;
        }elseif ($curStoreId == 6){
            $href = $this->transFrenchToItalian($href);
            return $href;
        }else {
            return $href;
        }
    }

    public function getEnglishCanadaUrl()
    {
        $curStoreId = Mage::app()->getStore()->getStoreId();
        $href = Mage::getUrl('', array('_current' => true,'_use_rewrite' => true,'_store' => 5,));
        $href = $this->cleanUrl($href);
        if ($curStoreId == 4) {
            $href = $this->transItalianToEnglish($href);
            return $href;
        } elseif($curStoreId == 6){
            $href = $this->transFrenchToEnglish($href);
            return $href;
        } else {
            return $href;
        }
    }

    public function getFrenchCanadaUrl()
    {
        $curStoreId = Mage::app()->getStore()->getStoreId();
        $href = Mage::getUrl('', array('_current' => true,'_use_rewrite' => true,'_store' => 6,));
        $href = $this->cleanUrl($href);
        if ($curStoreId == 1  || $curStoreId == 2 || $curStoreId == 5 ) {
            $href = $this->transEnglishToFrench($href);
            return $href;
        }elseif ($curStoreId == 4){
            $href = $this->transItalianToFrench($href);
            return $href;
        }else {
            return $href;
        }
    }

    public function cleanUrl($url)  // remove query string from href
    {
        $url = preg_replace('/\?.*/', '', $url);
        return $url;
    }

    public function transEnglishToItalian($url)
    {
        foreach ($this->englishItalian as $key => $value) {  // iterate over the array
            if (strpos($url,$key) !== false) {  // check if url has english translation word
                $url = str_replace($key, $value, $url);  // replace the english work with the Italian word
            }
        }
        return $url;
    }

    public function transItalianToEnglish($url)
    {
        foreach ($this->englishItalian as $key => $value) {
            if (strpos($url,$value) !== false) {
                $url = str_replace($value, $key, $url);
            }
        }
        return $url;
    }

    public function transEnglishToFrench($url)
    {

        foreach ($this->englishFrench as $key => $value) {
            if (strpos($url,$key) !== false) {
                $url = str_replace($key, $value, $url);
            }
        }
        return $url;
    }
    public function transFrenchToEnglish($url)
    {
        foreach ($this->englishFrench as $key => $value) {
            if (strpos($url,$value) !== false) {
                $url = str_replace($value, $key, $url);
            }
        }
        return $url;
    }

    public function transItalianToFrench($url)
    {
        foreach ($this->italianFrench as $key => $value) {
            if (strpos($url,$key) !== false) {
                $url = str_replace($key, $value, $url);
            }
        }
        return $url;
    }

    public function transFrenchToItalian($url)
    {
        foreach ($this->italianFrench as $key => $value) {
            if (strpos($url,$value) !== false) {
                $url = str_replace($value, $key, $url);
            }
        }
        return $url;
    }
}
```

Comment: thank you that works much better. I must of had some small syntax error when I tried it after your comment